# Calling a variable outside the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I use `var as` so that it can be called from outside a function? I've tried a lot of things but it's still not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#list').bind('click', function() {
    var as = $("#list").val(); 
  }); 
});

if (as == null) {
  d["subtypes"] = d; 
} else { 
  d["subtypes"] = as; 
}
```

Comment: regardless of how you can or can't access `as` - your code can be rewritten as `d.subtypes = d;` - because changing `as` in a click function wont re-run the code after it

Comment: I've tried the way above, but there's still an error with the message "not defined" in the if statement. I am really confused. Understand I just learned

Comment: yes, I'm just telling you, accessing `as` from outside the click function won't help

Comment: you can try using 'as' without 'var' for global scope

Answer (score 0):

Declare your variable outside the event  listener.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var as="";
$('#list').bind('click',function(){
 as = $("#list").val(); 
}); 
}); 
if (as == null) {
 d["subtypes"] = d; 
}else{ 
d["subtypes"] = as; 
}
```

Comment: so, the whole code boils down to  ... `d.subtypes = ""` - everything else is irrelevant :p

Comment: I've tried the way above, but there's still an error with the message "not defined" in the if statement. I am really confused. Understand I just learned

Answer (score 0):

variables declared inside a `function` is local to the function only. SO in this case the `var as` has scope to only the click handler function.

But if this variable is declared inside the `ready function` it will be accessible in all the function which are defined in ready handler

This snippet will help

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 var as; // here undefined, but it can be initialized with any value
$('#list').bind('click',function(){
  as = $("#list").val(); 
}); 
}); 
if (as == null) {
 d["subtypes"] = d; 
}else{ 
d["subtypes"] = as; 
}
```

Comment: so, the whole code boils down to  ... `d.subtypes = d` - everything else is irrelevant :p

Comment: I've tried the way above, but there's still an error with the message "not defined" in the if statement.

I am really confused. Understand I just learned

Answer (score 0):

```
var as ="";
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#list').bind('click',function(){
 a=$("#list").val(); 
if (as == null) {
 d["subtypes"] = d; 
}else{ 
d["subtypes"] = as; 
}
}); 
});
```

as jquery execute line by line .. you have to declared variable globel as above. and you have to write your code inside the click event

```
if(as == null) 
        {
        d["subtypes"] = d; 
        }else{ 
        d["subtypes"] = as; 
        }
```

as shown.declare variable with `""` as  `var as ="";`